# How to drag 4 non child windows as one unit

Tags: animation, scripting, autohotkey

Edit: I would like the dragging to appear "smooth" -- the refresh rate of each docked window while dragging to stay above 15 frames per second.

I've written this AutoHotKey script to demonstrate the concept but the animation is far from smooth.

(For this demo script to work, you must open 5 copies of notepad and save the documents as XXX1 ... XXX5)

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

WinGetPos,x1,y1,w1,h1,XXX1
WinGetPos,x2,y2,w2,h2,XXX2
WinGetPos,x3,y3,w3,h3,XXX3
WinGetPos,x4,y4,w4,h4,XXX4
WinGetPos,x5,y5,w5,h5,XXX5
yy1:=y1

Loop
{
  xx1:=x1
  WinGetPos,x1,y1,w1,h1,XXX1
  If (x1<>xx1)
    moveAll()
}

return

moveAll()
{
  global
  WinMove,XXX1,,%x1%,%yy1%
  x:=x1+w1
  WinMove,XXX2,,%x%,%yy1%
  x+=w2
  WinMove,XXX3,,%x%,%yy1%
  x+=w3
  WinMove,XXX4,,%x%,%yy1%
  x+=w4
  WinMove,XXX5,,%x%,%yy1%
}
```

Can anyone either optimize this script or suggest a proven method? (Or even show that it can't be done.) If it needs to be written in another language, so be it. It appears that Windows is limiting the repainting of windows to a certain total number of repaints on screen per second.

Comment: What is your definition of *smooth* and *not smooth*, repectively? Nobody can really imagine what you mean if they can't see it. Can you provide a screen capture and/or an example script that can be run out of the box?

Comment: As the notepad window XXX1 is dragged, the other windows follow it but each following window refreshes less than 4 times per second. My definition of "smooth" would be each following window refresh at least 15 times per second. Providing an out of the box runnable would be more complicated than the script itself is so far. Easiest to manually create 5 XXXn.txt documents (where n=[1-5]) and run this script.

Comment: Since one can only guess, I suggest you try out a Timer for each window. Maybe, they have a multithreading-like effect.

Comment: I've seen the same problem-effect with certain programs placing buttons on window title-bars.  I've also seen some programs that seem to have overcome that problem.  Listary for example can dock it's toolbar to a window and there is no flickering when the main window is dragged.  So, I think it is possible what you are wanting to do.  As to how, well, that's the question isn't it?  I suggest you change your title to something like "How to drag four non-child windows as on unit".  It would help to un-localize your problem.

Comment: @BGM I'm changing the title per your suggestion. I've placed windows and controls on other programs' title bars and such but never had this slow refresh problem doing that. It must either be related to screen area being refreshed or total number of separate window refreshes per second.

Comment: @MCL I didn't ignore your suggestion. It didn't work in AutoHotKey because "Although AutoHotkey doesn't actually use multiple threads, it simulates some of that behavior: If a second thread is started -- such as by pressing another hotkey while the previous is still running -- the current thread will be interrupted (temporarily halted) to allow the new thread to become current." (from http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm) If you have reason to believe the refresh is being limited by concurrency on a thread, it might be worth the time for me to rewrite in another language.

Comment: It is almost certainly being limited by concurrency. Anyway, it might improve by using timers, because some commands lead to an "internal waiting" state, that can be used to execute something else. Also, try `SetBatchLines, -1`, this should improve the execution speed dramatically. Give timers a try and see what happens.

Comment: Also, `SetWinDelay` might be of help.

Comment: @MCL Pleas turn your comment on `SetWinDelay` into an answer and I'll accept it. That was the problem. I tried 0 initially but it caused erratic behavior. `setwindelay, 5` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, `SetWinDelay, -1` and `SetBatchLines, -1` will make it *smoother*. I disagree with using `SetWinDelay, 5`, since we want the pause between two `WinMove`s to be as small as possible. Although probably not noticebale to the naked eye, `-1` will minimize that pause.